# Playwright - Login problem with Azure B2C login

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure-ad-b2c, playwright, e2e

I'm trying to do some tests with playwright. I use Azure B2C for the login service. I have followed the authentication documentation on official website: [Playwright auth documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/auth)

I have created a global-setup

```
    // global-setup.ts
    import { chromium, FullConfig } from '@playwright/test';

    async function globalSetup(config?: FullConfig) {
      const browser = await chromium.launch();
      const context = await browser.newContext();
      const page = await context.newPage();

      await page.goto('https://myapp.it/it');
      await page.click('text=Prosegui');
      await page.waitForSelector('input[id="email"]');
      await page.fill('input[id="email"]', 'usertest1@myapp.it');
      await page.waitForSelector('text=Password');
      await page.fill('text=Password', 'mypassword');
      await page.click('text=Accesso');
      // Save signed-in state to 'storageState.json'.
      await page.context().storageState({ path: 'storageState.json' });

      await browser.close();
    }

    export default globalSetup;
```

and I have defined the config in this way:

```
    // playwright.config.ts
    import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';

    const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
      globalSetup: require.resolve('./global-setup'), 
      // Use the default browser options, but override the
      // headless mode.globalSetup: require.resolve('./global-setup'),

      use: {
        headless: false,
        video: 'retain-on-failure',
        viewport: { width: 1280, height: 720 },
        baseURL: 'https://myapp.it/it/',
        storageState: 'storageState.json',
        //bypassCSP: true,
      },
    };
    export default config;
```

Now, I have multiple files for multiple tests. If I debug global-setup function it works correctly, it do the login correctly but If I run other tests, the context of new browser doesn't add cookies stored in storageState.json and I'm not logged in.

```
    import { test } from '@playwright/test';
    //onboarding.spec.ts
    test('onboarding', async ({ baseURL, page, context }) => {

      await page.goto(baseURL);
      await page.waitForSelector('text=Dashboard');
      await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'arrow_forward_ios' }).click();
      await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'arrow_forward_ios' }).click();
      await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'arrow_forward_ios' }).click();
      // await page.goto(`${baseURL}get-folder/details/**`);
      await page.waitForNavigation({ url: 'get-folder/details/**' });
      await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'arrow_forward_ios' }).click();
      await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'arrow_forward_ios' }).click();
      await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'arrow_forward_ios' }).click();
      await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'arrow_forward_ios' }).click();
      await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'arrow_forward_ios' }).click();
      await page.getByText('Conferma').click();
      // Use a glob URL pattern. Note no await.
      await page.waitForResponse('/services/api/identity/tutorial/**');
    });
```

If I run this test I can't proceed it because I'm not logged in and I'm unauthorized. I can't understand why cookies are not present in the context of new browser. What could be a solution?

Comment: According to code you're doing it correctly, maybe you need wait until result page loaded after you clicked login. Only after save storageState

Comment: I tried adding waitForTimeout before and after storageState function invocation...but it doesn't work

Comment: Well, in this case, nobody can guess it. You can generate your cookie json manually with `npx playwright codegen --save-storage=storageState.json` and rerun without globalSetup.  Maybe you miss something in your globalsetup

Comment: alternative - Azure B2C implementation in your case doesn't allow to save user sessions, each one is unique and removed from the server after the browser closed. Check if you have remember me option on login screen, maybe this will change auth behavior

Comment: And I would try to use `await page.waitForLoadState("networkidle");` before saving auth storage

Comment: The data needed is probably not in the `localStorage`but rather in the `sessionStorage` which is currently not included in the `stateStore` by Playwright. Consider implementing a localStorage strategy for your auth store or use this workaround: https://playwright.dev/docs/auth#session-storage